# ruby のメソッドに対して、期待引数個数の range を取得したい

Tags: ruby

ruby の特定のメソッドが、期待する引数の個数を range で取得したいと考えました。

どういうことかというと、 ruby にはデフォルト引数があるので、例えば以下のメソッドでは 0~2 個の引数を指定できます。

```
def hoge(a=1, b=2)
  p a; p b
end
```

この場合は、 `0..2` を取得したいです。

本家で検索したところ、 `arity` メソッドがそれらしかったのですが、`arity` メソッドは、可変長パラメータを引数に取る場合には、「(-1)*(必須parameterの個数+1)」が帰ってくる様子です。実際上記`hoge`メソッドに対して実行すると、`-1`が返ってきます。

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590080/is-there-a-way-to-know-how-many-parameters-are-needed-for-a-method

#### 質問

- ruby で、対象のメソッドが、実際に何個の引数を取り得るかの range を取得したいです。これは、実現可能でしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

丁度、質問投稿を見直していると、 accepted answer の下の方に、`Method#parameters` メソッドについての説明がありました。これを実際に実行してみると、

```
method(:hoge).parameters
# => [[:opt, :a], [:opt, :b]]
```

となったので、これが欲しかったメソッドの様子です。